# How to tell if you can trust a loan company?

Tags: banking, loans, security

What do you look for? Good UI design? BBB accreditation? Yelp, NYTimes mentions?

What should I expect of the customer service when making my decision to take out a loan?

What information should I look for on their website?

Should there be a physical branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for people who have done business with them. If you don't know anyone who has used their services, look for a company that at least has a brick and mortar branch in your area. Being able to deal with them face to face is a must.

Have you checked with your local bank?

Comment: Or banks, plural. And don't forget credit unions, which these days are more like a traditional savings-and-loan than most banks are. ...

Remember that no matter who you get a (normal) loan from, there is a good chance that the loan will be sold to a larger bank for processing... so face-to-face may not be relevant after the negotiation process.